# Different routes for rx and tx

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

Scenario:

- Server A has a well known IP address that clients can connect to. Server B does not.
- Server A can easily retrieve the IP address of Server B.
- Network egress from Server A is extremely expensive in dollars. Network ingress is free.
- Both ingress and egress on Server B are free.
- Clients send TCP and UDP traffic

Would it be possible to have clients connect to Server A, forward those packets to Server B, and have Server B respond directly to the clients (don't include server A in the round trip)?

I'm having a hard time imaging how this would work; it seems there are 3 pieces of information needed. Client address Server A address Server B address

Server A receives packet from client, sends packet to Server B, but how does Server B know the client address and the address of Server A in order to send the packet back? This assumes the packet received by the client must use the client address and the address of Server A.

Could this be solved using DNAT/SNAT to include the client and Server A addresses in the packets received by Server B? I'm assuming that would require some additional routing rules on both server A and server B.

**Edit**
When I mention "address" I am referring to the combination of IP address and Port number which I assume are required to reach the desired socket as the scenario being considered here is for TCP or UDP traffic.

Comment: You probably need server C, a machine with none of the limitations of A or B to mediate the connection.

Comment: You mean something like a [content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)? Other then that more details are required, what kind of traffic are we talking, how are the servers connected, etc.

Comment: AFAIK CDNs respond directly to client as they typically act as a pull through cache so I don't think that would work here.

Comment: For the case of discussion let's say it's TCP traffic. Server A communicates with server B over public internet routes. Client communicate with server A over public internet routes.

Comment: The only way I can think to make this work is by having Server B do SNAT and DNAT updating the packets to have the Client address and the address of Server A. For that to work Server B would need to know both addresses, but I'm not sure how that would work without embedding one of the addresses in the Options of the IP packet. In theory possible, but would require custom routing software?

Comment: I think clients will drop responses from server B. As most NAT/Firewalls have (spi). It's like having a conversation with a friend in public, and a stranger you have never met or talked to jumps in for a response to what you said to a friend. You will most likely respond, I don't know you, and we weren't talking to you! That's pretty much what the clients firewall will do. You may be able to spoof the server-a ip address or trick the client into thinking it's still having a conversation with server-a.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SPI, but it sounds like it is tracking packet addresses (IP address + port). In the scenario I'm proposing above, I'm assuming that Server B must respond with both the correct IP address and port.

Comment: @cvgw usually DNAT and SNAT is handled by the same device so this problem does not occur. But you can't do that since you need to avoid "return" traffic on server A. I addressed this issue in my answer.

Comment: @cvgw see updates to my answer (in response to the "port"-addition of your question)

Comment: Are server-A & server-B both at the same physical location? Btw (spi) = stateful packet inspection. In the simplest terms, it's keeping track of legitimate conversations that are taking place.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart, no the two servers and clients are all in different physical locations.

Answer (score 0):

Note, this is **very generally** speaking (to general for my taste, but since your question was a very general one, here we go):

- Client has IP_c
- Server A has IP_a
- Server B has IP_b

It would go like this. **Note:** for simplicity sake (and so I don't have to rewrite my answer after you added the port requirement to your question) I don't include the port but even with the port the principle stays the same:

- Client sends a packet to IP_a
- Server A forwards the packet to Server B by changing the destination IP from IP_a to IP_b using DNAT (source remains IP_c). Note: theoretically it doesn't have to be Server A doing the forward but some router before Server A but that depends on the specific network setup.

For the return packet:

- Without any further modification the return packet will have IP_c as destination and IP_b as source, in this case the Client will not recognize the packet because it has a different source IP so this won't work.
- To save the day Server B (or another router along the return path, again depending on the specific networksetup) has to change the source from IP_b to IP_a using SNAT.
- Note (this is where the actual custom part lies, since regular NAT solution don't do that by default): this has to be setup very carefully otherwise it will seriously hinder direct network communication with Server B using IP_b. Server B (or whatever device does the SNAT) has to know when to replace the source IP because the initial packet was forwarded and when to keep source IP being IP_b because the initial packet was send directly to IP_b. Same goes for Server A. There might be other problems to address as well, but this will be the major one.

To answer your question: yes, in general this "works" **but** you will keep the traffic from Server A to Server B. Since outgoing traffic from Server B is expensive, your suggested solution will only solve your initial problem for cases where we can assume the majority of the generated traffic will be outgoing traffic from Server B and traffic to Server A which has to be forwarded is negligible.

What you actually need to do is for the client to contact Server B directly without going through Server C otherwise you won't get rid of the costs. This is usually done by using a domain name to access Server A then the client will ask the DNS to which IP address to send the traffic.

In regards to your "sub-question":

> Server A receives packet from client, sends packet to Server B, but
> how does Server B know the client address and the address of Server A
> in order to send the packet back?

This is not how routing or NAT works. Usually only the destination IP (and/or port) gets changed (from A to B) and on the return packet the source IP gets changed back (from B to A). This is usually done by the same device so keeping track is not a problem. But you can't use this solution because in your case it will not avoid the outgoing traffic from Server A. So Server A will just use DNAT... (see above)

Comment: To clarify, egress from Server B is free. It is egress from Server A that is expensive.

Comment: Regarding the subquestion; it seems in theory that it would be possible to embed the IP address + port information of Server_A inside the IP headers to be consumed by Server_B (or some other routing application). In this scenario couldn't one use something like a custom netfilter hook to update the source address to match that of Server_A?

Comment: @cvgw again, this is not how NAT works. No additional information gets embedded, NAT actually changes the destination IP address (and source IP for the return packet). But you have to use some kind of "injection" to solve the problem with direct traffic to Server A and B (see above).

Comment: @cvgw I know Server B traffic is free but you still have to cover the expenses for traffic from Server A to Server B, so the NAT solution will not work for scenarios where the traffic to Server A is significant in volume=expenses.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I misunderstood your comment and I should have clarified that I am assuming in this scenario the egress from Server A to Server B is of acceptable volume.

Comment: Regarding embedding the additional data, I should have clarified that I am proposing using something like a custom netfilter hook on Server A to embed the additional information and a second hook on Server B to consume the information.

Comment: @cvgw as long as you can add the data without "breaking" the protocols basic functionality it should work. But that depends on the implementation. Am I wrong when I assume you don't know much about NAT? If not, there are a lot of easy examples out there (articles and youtube etc.), I think it would help you to read up a bit so you know the basics, especially if you want to implement this. Just as a friendly advice, don't take it the wrong way.